# Upload Image + Text Then Display On Page

Tags: php

Like I have mentioned in previous questions, I am currently working on my own forum that I have been working on the past few months. I want to be able to allow users to upload pictures in their post or replies.

I know the HTML will look something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="imgUpload" id="imgUpload">
```

But it's the PHP of processing it and then actually displaying the image. I have looked at a tutorial on W3Schools, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, but I can't get it to work.

Here's an example of when a user submits a new post on my site:

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

$host = "host"; // Host name
$username = "username"; // Mysql username
$password = "password"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "db"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "users"; // Table name
$tbl_name2 = "fquestions"; // Table name
$error_page ="../error-message"; //Error Page

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//Checks if user is logged in and account is active (not banned)
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true && $rows['active'] == 1) {

    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => 'secret_key',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'CAPTCHA Not Checked!';
        header( "Location: $error_page" );
    } else {

        // get data that sent from form 
        $topic = $_POST['topic'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $detail = $_POST['detail'];
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];

        $datetime = date("d/m/y h:i:s"); //create date time

        //Inserts information to database
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(topic, detail, username, email, datetime)VALUES('$topic', '$detail', '$username', '$email', '$datetime')";

        if (empty($topic) || empty($username) || empty($email)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Missing information!';
            header( "Location: $error_page" );
        } else {
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        }

    if($result) {
        $sql3 = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM $tbl_name2";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);
        $id = $row[0];

        //Redirects to topic page
        header('Location: view-topic?id='.$id.'');
        } else {
            echo "ERROR";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>You must be signed in to add a new topic</p>';
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

After the CAPTCHA check is completed, I want to be able to check if the user has submitted an image or not. If they have, upload that to a directory, which is created when they sign up, e.g. uploads/username/ and then process the text. If not then it just processes the text they inputted just as normal.

As for displaying it to the page I am not so sure as you would need some sort of ID I suppose or maybe get the image name to display it. It would really be appreciated if I could get this to work.

Comment: Try and stay away from w3schools. It's full of wickedly outdated advice and extraordinarily bad code.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. With those you have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. What you have here is a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between. File attachments are a solved problem.

Comment: MySQL uses the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format, `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `/`.

Comment: The date is stored as a string not an actual date

Comment: I get that, what I'm saying is when storing in the database you should store it as a `DATETIME` *and* use ISO-8601 formatting with `-`, never `/`.

Comment: No because if the user edits their post or reply, it will change the string to 'edited: ' followed by the date. Also thank you for the heads up on the injection bug, so far the only bug I knew of was the <script></script> injection

Comment: You can store the date in a `DATETIME` and then format it however you like for the user depending on their time-zone and locale settings.

Comment: Also I don't quite get how to prevent the SQL injection in my case. Could you give me some sort of example with my code?

Comment: My original comment has a link to how to use parameterized queries and `bind_param`, which is the key to fixing that.

Comment: Yeah I looked at them but don't really get it. My code looks a lot different.

Comment: That's the problem. You need your code to look a lot more like the code [in the examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). I'm going to reiterate here, because this stuff is *extremely important*, that using an ORM and/or framework would help significantly in this regard.

Comment: I looked at some of these frameworks and I don't see any that tell me how to install not using XAMPP, I have an actual website that uses text editors

Comment: All these frameworks are just PHP code. The examples are just XAMPP for convenience, not as a hard requirement. You can use Vagrant, a VM, a physical server, a local dev instance, it doesn't matter. Laravel, for example, installs using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org).

Comment: I just tried doing the sql injection attack on a test table of mine and no matter how I do it, the table doesn't drop. Also how would the attacker know what the name of my table is when trying the attack?

Comment: Attackers have a huge bag of tricks to draw on, not all of them obvious. If you're curious about how to test for this, a [tool like SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org) can help.